# Google forms custom field validation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I've a form that I created using google forms. Now there two optional fields. I did not make these two fields as required fields. Now what I want is that if the user provides a value to the first optional field then the second optional field becomes mandatory. How can I achieve that. Also how to restrict a text field to accept only numbers. I'm just starting out on google app scripts. Kinda missing something here, in spite of setting up a script with just an alert inside a function which is triggered on form submit nothing happens. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of right now, Google Forms does not have the ability to do form validation until after the form is submitted.

If you wanted in-form validation, you could create your own form using the script's UiApp or HTMLService. There are some tutorials for validating within that context.

Comment: Can you point to a link or code that helps show how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You can use jquery validation: http://questiontrack.com/form-validation-using-jquery-validation-1172784.html